# SCCM 2007 Java Query

Tags: sql, sccm

I would like to generate a query that lists all PCs with any version of Java except for 6.  They query I have created shows PCs with any version of Java including 6, I want to list ONLY PCs that have Java BUT not 6.

Here is what I got...

```
SELECT 
    arp.DisplayName0 AS 'Product',
    arp.Version0 AS 'Version',
    sys.Name0 AS 'PC Name'
FROM
    v_Add_Remove_Programs arp 
    INNER JOIN v_R_System sys ON arp.ResourceID=sys.ResourceID
WHERE
    arp.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Java%' AND
    arp.Publisher0 LIKE '%Oracle%' AND
    arp.Version0 NOT LIKE '%6%'
GROUP BY
    arp.DisplayName0,
    arp.Version0,
    sys.Name0
```

Table Structure:

```
Product     Version                         PC Name 
Java        7 Update 10 7.0.100             PC1 
Java        7 Update 10 7.0.100             PC2 
Java        7 Update 11 7.0.110             PC3 
Java        7 Update 13 7.0.130             PC4 
Java        7 Update 13 7.0.130             PC5 
Java        7 Update 13 (64-bit) 7.0.130    PC6
```

Comment: What does your data look like?  The use of `LIKE` with both a leading and trailing wildcard looks concerning.

Comment: The data shows PCs that have all versions of Java except for 6, but the problem is that some of these PCs ALSO have 6 installed along with 7 or 8. I want just the PCs with 7 or 8 installed but dont ALSO have 6 installed.

Comment: I mean, what does the data *physically* look like.  Can you include sample data from your tables?

Comment: Product  Version  PC Name 
Java 7 Update 10 7.0.100 PC1
Java 7 Update 10 7.0.100 PC2
Java 7 Update 11 7.0.110 PC3
Java 7 Update 13 7.0.130 PC4
Java 7 Update 13 7.0.130 PC5
Java 7 Update 13 (64-bit) 7.0.130 PC6

Comment: For example PC4 has Java 7 installed, but ALSO has Java 6 installed.  I don't want PC4 to show in this list if Java 6 is also installed.

Comment: Updated answer to filter those out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  After seeing the comments about some PC's having multiple versions installed, you'll want to use a `NOT EXISTS` query to filter out any PC that has version 6 installed.

```
SELECT      DISTINCT 
            arp.DisplayName0        AS 'Product',
            arp.Version0            AS 'Version',
            sys.Name0               AS 'PC Name'
FROM        v_Add_Remove_Programs   arp 
INNER JOIN  v_R_System              sys ON  arp.ResourceID = sys.ResourceID
WHERE       arp.DisplayName0 = 'Java' 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT      *
    FROM        v_Add_Remove_Programs   arp1
    INNER JOIN  v_R_System              sys1    ON  arp1.ResourceID = sys1.ResourceID
    WHERE       sys1.Name0 = sys.Name0
    AND         arp1.DisplayName0 = 'Java'
    AND         arp1.Version0 LIKE '6%'
)
```

Comment: I think it is working now Siyual, I changed the display name to LIKE % and am getting hits now, thank you, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to just exclude ResourceIds which have version 6:
`SELECT
    arp.DisplayName0 AS 'Product',
    arp.Version0 AS 'Version',
    sys.Name0 AS 'PC Name'
FROM
    v_Add_Remove_Programs arp 
    INNER JOIN v_R_System sys ON arp.ResourceID=sys.ResourceID
WHERE
    arp.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Java%' AND
    arp.Publisher0 LIKE '%Oracle%' AND 
    arp.ResourceID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT ResourceID
        FROM v_Add_Remove_Programs
        WHERE 
            arp.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Java%' AND
            arp.Publisher0 LIKE '%Oracle%' AND
            arp.Version0 LIKE '%6%'

    )

GROUP BY
    arp.DisplayName0,
    arp.Version0,
    sys.Name0`

Comment: Matt, I just tried yours and am still getting PCs that have both 6 and 7 installed on the same PC.

Comment: And Siyual, I get no records back from yours and I know there are PCs that have 7 and not 6 installed.